# Send query to database while closing browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

On my website [name combiner](https://www.mygirlynames.com/combine-names), I want to send query to database  while closing browser i have tried this script but it didn't execute the query in database to change the value of column statue

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
     <?php 

    include('config/configuration.php'); 
    $uid=$_GET['id_p'];
    $statue_pharmacie = mysql_query('update pharmacies set statue=0 where id="'.$uid.'"');



     ?>
    return inFormOrLink ? "Do you really want to close?" : null; 
   
   
});
```

Comment: Impossible. JS runs on the client, PHP runs on the server. Your PHP code ran at the time the page was generated and left absolutely NOTHING inside your js code on the client. You could have your beforeunload make an ajax requset to the server to try and do this, but since the browser's shutting down, there's no guarantee there'll be enough time for the request to ever get onto the wire.

Comment: As above, i think you're mixing up PHP and javascript. Take a look at [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and create a php file to handle the database logic

Comment: so there is no way to make update to database while closing browser =/?@MarcB

Comment: @SteveReck As mentioned above, you'd have to use AJAX. When the browser is closed, use JS to trigger an AJAX call to a PHP script that runs your query.

Comment: @versalle88 can you give an example?

Comment: @SteveReck I've added a basic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic example (assumes you're using jQuery), but I would be cautious as unload events typically have varied browser support:

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
// Grab ID for use later
var data = <?php (isset($_GET['id_p']) ? (int) $_GET['id_p'] : 0); ?>;

// On page unload
$( window ).unload(function() {
    // Send data to script
    $.post( "ajax.php", function( data ) {
        // Handle return
    });
});
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
// Make sure 0 wasn't passed
if (!empty($_POST['data'])) {
    // Run query
}
```

You can read about AJAX here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and the shorthand POST here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Also, I would stay away from the MySQL library of PHP as it's deprecated. You should be using PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Thanks,

Andrew